# Send emails to different addresses based on drop-menu selection

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a very basic skills, but this shouldn't be too hard. 
I have a very basic html form:

```
                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">LOCATION</div>
                    <select id="form-select">
                        <option>GENERAL ENQUIRY</option>
                        <option>SHOP 1</option>
                        <option>SHOP 2</option>
                        <option>SHOP 3</option>
                        <option>SHOP 4</option>
                        <option>SHOP 5</option>
                        <div class="down-box"><i class="typcn typcn-chevron-down"></i></div>
                    </select>

                </div>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">NAME</div>
                    <input id="form-name" required type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">EMAIL</div>
                    <input id="form-email" required type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">TELEPHONE</div>
                    <input id="form-telephone" required type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">MESSAGE</div>
                    <textarea id="form-msg" type="text"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-title">&nbsp;</div>
                    <button id="form-send">SEND</button>
                </div>

            </div><!--end of form holder-->
```

and a very basic mail.php to send email from the form:

```
    <?php
if ($_POST) {
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $text  = $_POST['text'];
    $option = $_POST['option'];
    $headers = $option . "\r\n" . $name . "\r\n" . $email . "\r\n" . $telephone;


    //send email   
    mail("email@email.com", "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);
}

?>
```

Now, I want to modify this php to send the email to different addresses based on the selection from the drop menu. How do I achieve this? 
(Eg. if a user picks SHOP1 email goes to shop1@email..., SHOP2 email to shop2@email.. etc.. etc..)

Thank you to everyone in advance!

Comment: You `<select>` tag has no `name` atttribute. Your `<option>` tags have no `value` attributes. So your `$_POST['option']` will always be undefined. Finally, you have to test using `isset()` the keys of `$_POST`, instead of what, you'll get some _"undefined index"_ notices.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all your inputs, selects, and textareas have no `name` attribute, so no values will be sent from them to your `$_POST[x];`.

---

**HTML:**

As @Syscall said in a comment, the name and values in your `select` are missing. Here's an example of what it should look like:

```
<select id="form-select" name="sendTo">
  <option value="general-enquiry">GENERAL ENQUIRY</option>
  <option value="shop-1">SHOP 1</option>
  <option value="shop-2">SHOP 2</option>
  [...]
</select>
```

I highly recommend **not** to work with e-mail addresses in the values, otherwise it can be processed quickly and abused for spaming or other things.

---

**PHP:**

In PHP you can then work with an `array`, a `if` or a `switch` to send the message to the desired e-mail address.

As an example here with a switch:

```
switch ($_POST['sendTo']) {
  case 'shop-1':
    $sendTo = 'shop-1@mail.com';
    break;

  case 'shop-2':
    $sendTo = 'shop-2@mail.com';
    break;

  [...]

  default:
    $sendTo = 'general-enquiry@mail.com';
    break;
}

mail($sendTo, 'Mail Enquiry', $text, $headers);
```

---

I hope that could help :)

---

### Update #1

On request, once the entire necessary code.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="sendMail" value="1" />

  <label for="sendTo">Location</label>
  <select id="sendTo" name="sendTo">
    <option value="general-enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
    <option value="shop-1">Shop 1</option>
    <option value="shop-2">Shop 2</option>
    <option value="shop-3">Shop 3</option>
    <option value="shop-4">Shop 4</option>
    <option value="shop-5">Shop 5</option>
  </select>

  <label for="name">Name <em>(required)</em></label>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name ..." required />

  <label for="email">Email <em>(required)</em></label>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your best email ..." required />

  <label for="telephone">Telephone <em>(required)</em></label>
  <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter your phone number ..." required />

  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="If you have a message for us or one of our shops, please enter them here ..."></textarea>

  <input type="submit">Send</input>

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if ($_POST['sendMail']) {
  if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    return 'Please enter your full name!';
  }

  if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    return 'Please enter your email!';
  }

  if (empty($_POST['telephone'])) {
    return 'Please enter your phone number!';
  }

  $subject   = 'Mail Enquiry';
  $name      = $_POST['name'];
  $email     = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

  $message .= 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n";
  $message .= 'Email: ' . $email . "\r\n";
  $message .= 'Telephone: ' . $telephone . "\r\n";

  if ($_POST['message']) {
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Message: ' . "\r\n";
    $message .= $_POST['message'];
  }

  switch ($_POST['sendTo']) {
    case 'shop-1':
      $sendTo = 'shop-1@yourdomain.com';

      break;

    case 'shop-2':
      $sendTo = 'shop-2@yourdomain.com';

      break;

    case 'shop-3':
      $sendTo = 'shop-3@yourdomain.com';

      break;

    case 'shop-4':
      $sendTo = 'shop-4@yourdomain.com';

      break;

    case 'shop-5':
      $sendTo = 'shop-5@yourdomain.com';

      break;

    default:
      $sendTo = 'general-enquiry@yourdomain.com';

      break;
  }

  $header .= 'To: ' . $sendTo . "\r\n";
  $header .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";

  if ($sendTo && $subject && $message && $header) {
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $header);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arne, thanks for your help. I tried using the switch as pointed out but no emails are being sent now.

Comment: @Wallyl81 I've updated my answer above once with all the necessary code. I hope he is mostly self-explanatory, but if you have any questions, you can ask them here of course. ;) Since I just wrote the code down quickly, I didn´t test it, but it should work. If you get any errors, please write them once as a comment. And just as a short side note, as I have have looked to your other comments, please use there backticks also for `code`, so we get a better readability there.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to set a `name` to your inputs,  so `<input id="form-name" required type="text">` becomes `<input id="form-name" name="name" required type="text">` if you want to access it through `$_POST['name']`
2. You need values for your select.

   ```
   <select id="form-select" name="shop-select">
     <option>GENERAL ENQUIRY</option>
     <option value="shop1">SHOP 1</option>
     <option value="shop2">SHOP 2</option>
     <option value="shop3">SHOP 3</option>
     <option value="shop4">SHOP 4</option>
     <option value="shop5">SHOP 5</option>
   <div class="down-box"><i class="typcn typcn-chevron-down"></i>
   ```

AND

```
    <?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $name  = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
        $text  = $_POST['text'];
        $option = $_POST['option'];
        $shop = $_POST['shop-select']
        $headers = $option . "\r\n" . $name . "\r\n" . $email . "\r\n" . 
        $telephone;

       //send email   
       mail(getEmail($shop), "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);
}

function getEmail($shop)  
{
    //an array of shops name and email that you get from somewhere
    // store it in database or as a constant somewhere ? or you can declare it here...
    $shops = [
        "shop1" => "someemail@email",
        // etc
    ];

    if (isset($shops[$shop]) && filter_var($shops[$shop], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       return $shops[$shop];
    }
        return "email@email.com";
}

?>
```

NEXT you'd want to do some input sanitization, and if your project is big enough, probably use a framework so all that stuff is already done for you...

Comment: not the best idea to put email addresses on a web site even in form values, bots harvest them for spamming, also any one could change the address and use this form for a 'limited' kind of spamming

Comment: yeah I just simplified it, I would have an array with shop number and related email addresses...

Comment: well, you need to have email sending set up properly on the server, that's another story...

Comment: @BenDubuisson Thanks!! But system is not sending emails. 
<select id="form-select" name="shop-select">
<option value="general-enquiry">SHOP1</option>
// etc
div class="down-box"><i class="typcn typcn-chevron-down"></i>
</select>

Mail.php:
mail(getEmail($shop), "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);
}
function getEmail($shop)  
{
    
$shops = [ "shop1" => "email1@email.com",  
// etc    
];
   
 if (isset($shops[$shop]) && filter_var($shops[$shop], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       return $shops[$shop];
    }
       
 return " email@email.com ";
}

Comment: is your server set up properly to send email? What is your system exactly?

Comment: Ben system has been sending emails fine so far. Only difference is now I need to send emails to different stores based on selection while before emails were all going to the same email. This works fine but with new code, nothing happens. Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: show me your `getEmail` function. Have you set emails properly in that array?

Comment: mail(getEmail($shop), "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);
}


function getEmail($shop)  
{
    

$shops = [
  
"shop1" => "email1@email.com",
  
"shop2" => "email2@email.com ",
  
// etc
    
];
   
 if (isset($shops[$shop]) && filter_var($shops[$shop], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       return $shops[$shop];
    }
       
 return " email@email.com ";
}

Comment: yes of course ben. I put my own email addresses to test it (I don't have access to the shops' emails).

Comment: One question, what is the return $shops... email for?

Comment: so it will return the right email address corresponding to the key in the array. If user chooses "shop1", it returns $shops["shop1"] which is the value of shop1 in the array (someemail@email)

Comment: if you replace `mail(getEmail($shop), "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);` by `mail("your actualemail", "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);` does it send ?

Comment: In the last line of the getMail function, you should also return the email you want it to send to by default if something goes wrong (as a fallback)

Comment: still not sending ben. I will look more into it. In the mean time, thanks anyway for your help!! Will keep you posted